# Can't disconnect interlock switch terminals from connectors

Tags: switch, plastic, connectors

I am trying to remove the interlock door switch in a GE microwave model JEB1860SM2SS. I was able to unhook it from the frame, but I can't pull the connecters off the terminals. The plastic that covers the connections will not budge. Is there a trick to sliding it off or do I have to break it and get a new one?

Comment: why are you removing an interlock switch on a microwave oven door?

Comment: please post a clear closeup picture of the connections on the switch

Comment: Some have a small tab in the center that lock them in place a small screwdriver is used to apply pressure and the 2 will slide apart sometimes after pulling on them you have to push them together press on the catch and slide them apart and yes I do understand you said they have plastic covers.