# Disengage microwave door switch from connector

Tags: switch, doors, connectors

I'm in the process of replacing my Whirlpool microwave's door faulty switch but unable to remove the connectors to install the new switch.  I'm afraid I'll damage the wiring if I apply too much force.  I don't see any latch, is there a tick to disengage it?

I came across this post that appears similar, but can't figure out where the "small tab in the center" is; maybe mine has a different connector type?  [Can't disconnect interlock switch terminals from connectors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209692/cant-disconnect-interlock-switch-terminals-from-connectors)

Attached is a photo to help explain the situation.  TYIA

[image]

Comment: If they do not pull apart, some have tiny locks/tabs inside the connector.  Can try pins, small metal pieces, but the easiest is to use a terminal removal tool/kit to unlock.  The big river in south america store has a bunch, but not the only place.

Comment: The tab will be inside where the wire goes.  A nice tight blind fit.

Comment: Try a screwdriver prying between the body of the switch and the connector.